# CSS only: When breaking a line then at a certain position in a sentence,

Tags: css, break, line-breaks, word-break

You see one centered sentence at a certain resolution:

[image]

In a smaller screen, you see the first line-breaking:

[image]

My desired result: If there is a first line-break then it should happen at a certain position, like:

[image]

Can I achieve that with CSS only solution?

**Codepen Example:**

https://codepen.io/webia1/full/zYrdXoZ

HTML and CSS parts are very easy:

```html
<div class="cTextContainer">
  Furl hands Pieces of Eight red 
  ensign parley lookout dance the 
  hempen jig chase guns main 
  sheet jolly boat. 
</div>
```

```css
.cTextContainer {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The following may not happen:

[image]

It is always a result desired something like:

[image]

**Please consider:** In the real example (a complicated scenario, too much time consuming to explain it here) I use calculations with `vw`and `vh` to scale the font-size. I would like to guarantee a similar look in every possible resolution (from mobile to big screens).

**EDIT:
I imagine something like: move 50% (2 lines) or 33% (3 lines etc.) of the text in the next line after or before a word. My current workaround is the changing box-width in relation to screen-width in many media-queries.**

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You would have to change the HTML structure. Wrap each line you don't want to break in a span and set those to inline block

Comment: dear @Paulie_D thank you very much, I'll try it,..

Comment: Now possible: `text-wrap: balance;`. (The balance value for text-wrap is part of CSS Text Level 4. See: https://caniuse.com/css-text-wrap-balance)

Answer (score 3):

You can use media queries for solving this type of issues.
Please find the code below, i think it will help you for solving your problem.

```
<div class="cTextContainer">
       Furl hands Pieces of Eight red 
  ensign parley lookout dance <br>the 
  hempen jig chase guns main 
  sheet jolly boat.
</div>

.cTextContainer {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}     
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) 
{
  .cTextContainer br 
  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jestin T Wilson, I know that is a possibility to solve this problem, but imagine you have to do so many manual interventions for every possible screen-resolution (in my case maybe 60 media-queries for each text part), which is not worth it in the end. There must be a ingenious solution. I imagine something like: move 50% of the text in the next line after or before a word,..

Answer (score 1):

You may use regular spaces only in places where you want to break the text, in all other places **use a non-breaking space** (&nbsp;).

E.g.:

```
my&nbsp;long&nbsp;text&nbsp;breaks&nbsp;here another&nbsp;line&nbsp;started
```

Worked for me